# imports in nested projects or own library dir

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-import

How i should import modules in nested dir projects or in own libs?
When...
Structure:

```
lib_dir
|-my_module_2.py
\_my_module.py
```

Belove code works when i run it from main lib dir

```py
#my_module.py
import my_module_2
```

But after creating library based on `lib_dir` i need to import like belove:

```py
#my_module.py
import lib_dir.my_module_2
```

Why? It's terribly annoying.

I have similar problem, when i creating a large project.

```
|
|-dir_lv1
|  |
|  |-dir_lv2
|  |   |
|  |    \module_lv2
|  |
|   \module_lv2
|
|
 \main.py
```

Running `main.py` requires to build all imports from `main.py` level in every module (`main`, `module_lv2`)  and it's impossible to run `module_lv2.py` rebuilding imports or tricks like belove:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # import from current file level
elif ...:
    # import from other level
```

or
`sys.path.append(__file__)`

Is it "one simple trick" to imports it?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `__init__.py` to declare your package.

```
lib_dir
|-__init__.py
|-my_module_2.py
\_my_module.py
```

In the `__init__.py` you could make your imports like

```
from my_module import my_func
from my_module_2 import my_class

__all__ = [my_func,my_class]
```

Then you can import `lib_dir` in other projects as package and use it

```
from lib_dir import my_func,my_class
```

Comment: I will test it in nearest future.

I found a simple way to add "dir of this module" to paths
```
import sys
import os  
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+__file__.rsplit('\\', 1)[0][1:])
```
And it append right path, but it doesnt work. Do you know why?

Comment: os.getcwd() returns the current_working_directory and varies depending of your working directory or where your script is called from, so everytime you call or import your modules from a new location it changes and therefore you get a wrong path added to your sys.path.